# Problems casting an address to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I understand that the address-of operator `&` stores the actual address of the variable. A pointer stores a reference to an address that I can access using the dereference operator `*`. What I am not understanding is how to make a pointer point to a given address. Non of the following have worked.

```cpp
void getDouble(double &addr) {
  // Incorrect type cast error
  std::cout << *((double *)addr) << std::endl;
  
  // Incorrect type cast error
  double *dbl = addr;
  std::cout << (double *)addr << std::endl;
```

What is the correct way to get the value from an address in C/C++?

Comment: In `void getDouble(double &addr)`, you have a reference, not a pointer.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: *I understand that the address-of operator* -- `double& addr` -- That is *not* the address-of operator.  Looks like you've been reading `C`-only books, where that symbol can only mean "address-of" in that language.

Comment: In C++ the same symbol can have different meanings based on context. Yes, the `&` operator gets you a pointer to an object, but `double &addr` is a different context. In that context, it means `addr` is a reference to a `double` and isn't related to the address-of operator.

Comment: I assume [this](https://onlinegdb.com/6Bij6avic) is what you wanted?
`void getDouble(double *addr)` accepts pointer to double and in your example it expects reference to the double.

Comment: In C++, an explicit conversion (in the form `(T)foo` like `(double*)addr`) will look like it fixes your problem because it will allow your code to compile, but in most cases this just makes the problem worse. It basically turns off the compiler's type checking, it's like silencing the fire alarm hoping it will put out the actual fire. If you really need a cast, the cast operators like `static_cast` are safer.

Comment: Okay so it's different in C++, whereas in C the & strictly means address-of, C++ actually lets you pass the reference directly, so what I have is not an address but an actual reference to the variable so I treat it exactly like the variable type it is. In this case, double. Got it.

Comment: @richbai90 -- In C++, that operator in the appropriate context also means "address-of", just like in C.   The problem is that you used that operator in a different context, i.e. as the reference operator.

Comment: @richbai90 That's correct.

Comment: It'll help you in the long run if you just pretend C is java, and C++ is C# (or an other unrelated pair of languages).  Some code might look similar, but they are different languages under the hood.  The same applies to C and C++, more so as they grow and diverge more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that the address-of operator & stores the actual address of the variable

An operator doesn't "store" anything. When you pass a value as the operand of built-in address-of operator, the resulting value is a pointer to the object. If the operand is a reference, then the result is a pointer to the referred object.

> A pointer stores a reference to an address

A pointer stores an address. The value of the pointer represents the address. Using the indirection operator, you can indirect through a pointer to get an lvalue referring to the pointed object.

> ```
> // Incorrect type cast error
> double *dbl = addr;
> ```

`addr` is a reference to a `double`. A reference to `double` doesn't implicitly convert to a pointer.

> ```
> // Incorrect type cast error
> std::cout << *((double *)addr) << std::endl;
> ```

A reference to `double` doesn't convert to a pointer even explicitly.

You can use the addressof operator to get a pointer to the referred object, if that's what you want to do:

```
double *dbl = &addr; // pointer to object referred by addr
```

> What is the correct way to get the value from an address in C++

If you have reference such as `addr` in the example, then you simply use the reference just like any other value. The reference will be implicitly indirected through and the value of the referred object is accessed. For example, if you want to print the value of the object:

```
std::cout << addr;
```

---

> Okay so it's different in C++, whereas in C the & strictly means address-of

It's important to understand that tokens have different meanings in different contexts. Example:

```
int i = 1 & 2;
//        ^--- bitwise-and operator (binary)
int* ptr = &i;
// ^       ^-- addressof operator (unary)
// ^---------- not an operator; signifies a pointer type
int i2 = *i * 42;
//       ^  ^- multiplication operator (binary)
//       ^---- indirection operator (unary)
int& ref = i;
// ^ not an operator; signifies a reference type
int i3 = ref; // automatic indirection
```

C++ and C are separate languages. C doesn't have reference variables; the example program would be simply ill-formed. It's best to not make assumptions about one language based on knowledge of another language.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that the address-of operator `&` stores the actual address of the variable.

It *returns* the address, it does not *store* the address anywhere.  You need a separate assignment to *store* that address somewhere, like in a pointer.

> A pointer stores a reference to an address

No, it stores the actual address.

> that I can access using the dereference operator `*`.

You dereference a pointer to access the data that is stored at the address which the pointer is pointing at.

> What I am not understanding is how to make a pointer point to a given address. Non of the following have worked.

That is because you are not actually using the address-of `&` operator to begin with.  `double &addr` declares a reference named `addr` that refers to a `double` somewhere.  It does not take the address of a `double` named `addr`.  A reference is just an alias, it is not a pointer (though most compilers will *implement* a reference using a pointer).

You need to use the actual address-of `&` operator (or `std::addressof()`), even if you are working with a reference to a variable.  Taking the address of a reference returns the address of the thing being referred to.

```cpp
void getDouble(double &dbl) {

  // prints the value of the double
  std::cout << dbl << std::endl;

  // prints the address of the double
  std::cout << &dbl << std::endl;

  // prints the value of the double
  std::cout << *(&dbl) << std::endl;
  
  // prints the address of the double
  double *addr = &dbl;
  std::cout << addr << std::endl;
  
  // prints the value of the double
  std::cout << *addr << std::endl;
}
```